# How to find zero crossings with hysteresis?

Tags: python, numpy, debouncing

In numpy, I would like to detect the points at which the signal crosses from (having been previously) below a certain threshold, to being above a certain other threshold.  This is for things like debouncing, or accurate zero crossings in the presence of noise, etc.

Like this:

```
import numpy

# set up little test problem
N = 1000
values = numpy.sin(numpy.linspace(0, 20, N))
values += 0.4 * numpy.random.random(N) - 0.2
v_high = 0.3
v_low = -0.3

# find transitions from below v_low to above v_high    
transitions = numpy.zeros_like(values, dtype=numpy.bool)

state = "high"

for i in range(N):
    if values[i] > v_high:
        # previous state was low, this is a low-to-high transition
        if state == "low":
            transitions[i] = True
        state = "high"
    if values[i] < v_low:
        state = "low"
```

I would like a way to do this without looping over the array explicitly: but I can't think of any way, since each state value depends on the previous state.  Is it possible to do without a loop?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This can be done like so:

```
def hyst(x, th_lo, th_hi, initial = False):
    hi = x >= th_hi
    lo_or_hi = (x <= th_lo) | hi
    ind = np.nonzero(lo_or_hi)[0]
    if not ind.size: # prevent index error if ind is empty
        return np.zeros_like(x, dtype=bool) | initial
    cnt = np.cumsum(lo_or_hi) # from 0 to len(ind)
    return np.where(cnt, hi[ind[cnt-1]], initial)
```

Explanation: `ind` are the indices of all the samples where the signal is below the lower or above the upper threshold, and for which the position of the 'switch' is thus well-defined. With `cumsum`, you make some sort of counter which points to the index of the last well-defined sample. If the start of the input vector is between the two thresholds, `cnt` will be 0, so you need to set the the corresponding output to the initial value using the `where` function.

Credit: this is a trick I found in an [old post](http://www.mathworks.it/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/277002) on some Matlab forum, which I translated to Numpy. This code is a bit hard to understand and also needs to allocate various intermediate arrays. It would be better if Numpy would include a dedicated function, similar to your simple for-loop, but implemented in C for speed.

Quick test:

```
x = np.linspace(0,20, 1000)
y = np.sin(x)
h1 = hyst(y, -0.5, 0.5)
h2 = hyst(y, -0.5, 0.5, True)
plt.plot(x, y, x, -0.5 + h1, x, -0.5 + h2)
plt.legend(('input', 'output, start=0', 'output, start=1'))
plt.title('Thresholding with hysteresis')
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: @SpaceDog You could, but if you are using C it is probably better to write a simple loop similar to what was in the original question. The trick in my answer is faster in Python, since it uses vectorized numpy code, instead of a slow Python loop. The vectorized code has to pass several times over the data, while a simple loop in C could do everything in one pass.

Comment: I asked that because I am trying to understand what your function does, so I can write a code in C... 

Comment: Thank you! This solution is using indices in a creative way and reminds me of APL.

Comment: This solution is incredibly clever, it took me a while to wrap my head around how this works. The key is to understand that there are two layers of indirection going on - `cnt-1` is an array of indices into `ind` which itself is an array of indices into `lo_or_hi`. `cnt` can be seen as "the number of outside values we've seen so far" and since `ind` is the list of indices of outside values, `cnt-1` de facto yields the *index* of the last outside value *index* to "latch on to". Very mind-bending.

Answer (score 4):

Modifications I had to do for my work, all based on the answer above by [Bas Swinckels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23291658/2330945), to permit detection of threshold-crossing when using standard as well as **reversed** thresholds.

I'm not happy with the naming tough, maybe it should now read `th_hi2lo` and `th_lo2hi` instead of `th_lo` and `th_hi`? Using the original values, the behaviour ist the same tough.

```
def hyst(x, th_lo, th_hi, initial = False):
    """
    x : Numpy Array
        Series to apply hysteresis to.
    th_lo : float or int
        Below this threshold the value of hyst will be False (0).
    th_hi : float or int
        Above this threshold the value of hyst will be True (1).
    """        

    if th_lo > th_hi: # If thresholds are reversed, x must be reversed as well
        x = x[::-1]
        th_lo, th_hi = th_hi, th_lo
        rev = True
    else:
        rev = False

    hi = x >= th_hi
    lo_or_hi = (x <= th_lo) | hi

    ind = np.nonzero(lo_or_hi)[0]  # Index für alle darunter oder darüber
    if not ind.size:  # prevent index error if ind is empty
        x_hyst = np.zeros_like(x, dtype=bool) | initial
    else:
        cnt = np.cumsum(lo_or_hi)  # from 0 to len(x)
        x_hyst = np.where(cnt, hi[ind[cnt-1]], initial)

    if rev:
        x_hyst = x_hyst[::-1]

    return x_hyst
```

And as above a test of the code to see what it does:

```
x = np.linspace(0,20, 1000)
y = np.sin(x)
h1 = hyst(y, -0.2, 0.2)
h2 = hyst(y, +0.5, -0.5)
plt.plot(x, y, x, -0.2 + h1*0.4, x, -0.5 + h2)
plt.legend(('input', 'output, classic, hyst(y, -0.2, +0.2)', 
            'output, reversed, hyst(y, +0.5, -0.5)'))
plt.title('Thresholding with hysteresis')
plt.show()
```

[image: Sine with two different settings for hysteresis.]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that achieves the exact same result as [the answer from Bas Swinckels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23291658/172594), and appears to have similar performance (in the order of 0.4 seconds for an array of 10 million elements when testing on Colab), but is easier to understand in my opinion:

```py
def hyst(x, th_lo, th_hi, initial = False):
    outside_values = np.full(x.size, np.nan)
    outside_values[0] = initial
    outside_values[x < th_lo] = 0
    outside_values[x > th_hi] = 1
    outside_value_indexes = np.where(np.isnan(outside_values), 0, np.arange(x.size))
    np.maximum.accumulate(outside_value_indexes, out=outside_value_indexes)
    return outside_values[outside_value_indexes]
```

And running the same test as the other answer:

```py
x = np.linspace(0,20, 1000)
y = np.sin(x)
h1 = hyst(y, -0.5, 0.5)
h2 = hyst(y, -0.5, 0.5, True)
plt.plot(x, y, x, -0.5 + h1, x, -0.5 + h2)
plt.legend(('input', 'output, start=0', 'output, start=1'))
plt.title('Thresholding with hysteresis')
plt.show()
```

[image: example]

The basic idea comes from [this answer to a separate question about forward-filling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41191127/172594):

1. First we create an `outside_values` array that maps values from the input to 0 if below threshold, 1 if above threshold, or NaN as a placeholder otherwise.
2. Then we create an `outside_values_indexes` array that lists all the indexes into `outside_values` (i.e. `[0, 1, 2, 3, ...]`). The indexes that map to inside values (NaNs) are replaced by 0.
3. We replace `outside_values_indexes` with its cumulative maximum, i.e. each index is replaced by the maximum of all indexes that precede it in the array. Since we set the indexes of inside values to 0, they never contribute to the maximum and instead the maximum index of all preceding outside values (or, in other words, the index of the last outside value previously seen) is used.
4. Now that `outside_values_indexes` maps each input value to the index of the last outside value, we can use that to index into `outside_values` and we're done!