# Fill zero values of 1d numpy array with last non-zero values

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say we have a 1d numpy array filled with some `int` values. And let's say that some of them are `0`.

Is there any way, using `numpy` array's power, to fill all the `0` values with the last non-zero values found?

for example:

```
arr = np.array([1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 6, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2])
fill_zeros_with_last(arr)
print arr

[1 1 1 2 2 4 6 8 8 8 8 8 2]
```

A way to do it would be with this function:

```
def fill_zeros_with_last(arr):
    last_val = None # I don't really care about the initial value
    for i in range(arr.size):
        if arr[i]:
            last_val = arr[i]
        elif last_val is not None:
            arr[i] = last_val
```

However, this is using a raw python `for` loop instead of taking advantage of the `numpy` and `scipy` power.

If we knew that a reasonably small number of consecutive zeros are possible, we could use something based on `numpy.roll`. The problem is that the number of consecutive zeros is potentially large...

Any ideas? or should we go straight to `Cython`?

#### Disclaimer:

I would say long ago I found a question in stackoverflow asking something like this or very similar. I wasn't able to find it. :-(

Maybe I missed the right search terms, sorry for the duplicate then. Maybe it was just my imagination...

Comment: If you don't mind using `pandas`, have a look at the `ffill` method (or see `fillna` for the complete story).  However, there's no "forward fill" type functionality built into numpy.

Comment: As @JoeKington mentions, `fillna` in pandas will do this. The Cython source is the `pad_2d_inplace_` function [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/src/generate_code.py#L460), specifically the inner loop at the bottom. The code is exactly what you have written in your example.

Comment: @JoeKington Thanks! nice feature! still I prefer to avoid depending on `pandas` for this...

Comment: You could also use `pandas.groupby()` in theory - though why bother since you have plenty of other solutions :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here's a solution using `np.maximum.accumulate`:

```
def fill_zeros_with_last(arr):
    prev = np.arange(len(arr))
    prev[arr == 0] = 0
    prev = np.maximum.accumulate(prev)
    return arr[prev]
```

We construct an array `prev` which has the same length as `arr`, and such that `prev[i]` is the index of the last non-zero entry before the *i*-th entry of `arr`. For example, if:

```
>>> arr = np.array([1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 6, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2])
```

Then `prev` looks like:

```
array([ 0,  0,  0,  3,  3,  5,  6,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7, 12])
```

Then we just index into `arr` with `prev` and we obtain our result. A test:

```
>>> arr = np.array([1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 6, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2])
>>> fill_zeros_with_last(arr)
array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 2])
```

**Note**: Be careful to understand what this does when the first entry of your array is zero:

```
>>> fill_zeros_with_last(np.array([0,0,1,0,0]))
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
```

Comment: Your answer is probably faster than mine - except in cases where my in-place operation might save time.

Comment: I tried a [similar approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30508234/3406193) myself, but still this one is at least as nice and faster. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by [jme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30489294/3406193)'s answer here and by [Bas Swinckels'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23291658/3406193) (in the linked question) I came up with a different combination of numpy functions:

```
def fill_zeros_with_last(arr, initial=0):
     ind = np.nonzero(arr)[0]
     cnt = np.cumsum(np.array(arr, dtype=bool))
     return np.where(cnt, arr[ind[cnt-1]], initial)
```

I think it's succinct and also works, so I'm posting it here for the record. Still, [jme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30489294/3406193)'s is also succinct and easy to follow and seems to be faster, so I'm accepting it :-)

Comment: Very nice... there is also a potential solution using `np.repeat`, but it seems to be a little trickier to get the boundaries right. It's probably not quite as fast as either of ours, too.

Answer (score 1):

If the `0`s only come in strings of 1, this use of `nonzero` might work:

```
In [266]: arr=np.array([1,0,2,3,0,4,0,5])
In [267]: I=np.nonzero(arr==0)[0]
In [268]: arr[I] = arr[I-1]
In [269]: arr
Out[269]: array([1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5])
```

I can handle your `arr` by applying this repeatedly until `I` is empty.

```
In [286]: arr = np.array([1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 6, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2])

In [287]: while True:
   .....:     I=np.nonzero(arr==0)[0]
   .....:     if len(I)==0: break
   .....:     arr[I] = arr[I-1]
   .....:     

In [288]: arr
Out[288]: array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 2])
```

If the strings of 0s are long it might be better to look for those strings and handle them as a block.  But if most strings are short, this repeated application may be the fastest route.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do expect potentially many consecutive `0`. I thought about something this, but the for loop just didn't convinced me... :-/