# pandas replace zeros with previous non zero value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
index = range(14)
data = [1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 6, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=index, columns = ['A'])
```

How can I fill the zeros with the previous non-zero value using pandas? Is there a fillna that is not just for "NaN"?.

The output should look like:

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 2, 1]
```

(This question was asked before here [Fill zero values of 1d numpy array with last non-zero values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30488961/fill-zero-values-of-1d-numpy-array-with-last-non-zero-values) but he was asking exclusively for a numpy solution)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can use `replace` with `method='ffill'`

```
In [87]: df['A'].replace(to_replace=0, method='ffill')
Out[87]:
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     2
5     4
6     6
7     8
8     8
9     8
10    8
11    8
12    2
13    1
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

To get numpy array, work on `values`

```
In [88]: df['A'].replace(to_replace=0, method='ffill').values
Out[88]: array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 2, 1], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: if looking to replace the value with another, say 1 do `df['A'].replace(to_replace=0,value = 1)`

Comment: This is not replacing 0 values in the dataframe, instead it is excluding those dataframe values and returning the rest of the dataframe. Can someone please suggest a better option?

Comment: Deprecated - currently raises FutureWarning. Rather see newer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77104004/12846804) by @HarryChil

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to do this now is:

`df.replace(0, np.nan).ffill()`

`df.replace(to_replace=0, method='ffill')` : this was deprecated in Pandas version 2.1.0.

Comment: Due to deprecation this should become the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

This is a better answer to the previous one, since the previous answer returns a dataframe which hides all zero values.

Instead, if you use the following line of code -

```
df['A'].mask(df['A'] == 0).ffill(downcast='infer')
```

Then this resolves the problem. It replaces all 0 values with previous values.