# numpy time series merge and fill missing values with earlier values

Tags: python, numpy

My data looks like this:

```
timedelta64 1, temp1A, temp 1B, temp1C, ...
timedelta64 2, temp2A, temp 2B, temp2C, ...
```

The data is ingested into two numpy arrays:

1. A series of times stamps `raw_timestamp`, `dtype=[('datetime', '<M8[s]')]`

   ```
   '2009-01-01T18:41:00', 
   '2009-01-01T18:44:00',
   '2009-01-01T18:46:00', 
   '2009-01-01T18:47:00',
   ```
2. A table of sensor data `raw_sensor`, `dtype=[ ('sensorA', '<u4'), ('sensorB', '<u4'), ('sensorC', '<u4'), ('sensorD', '<u4'), ('sensorE', '<u4'), ('sensorF', '<u4'), ('sensorG', '<u4'), ('sensorH', '<u4'), ('signal', '<u4')]`

   ```
    (755, 855, 755, 855, 743, 843, 743, 843, 2),
    (693, 793, 693, 793, 693, 793, 693, 793, 1),
    (755, 855, 755, 855, 743, 843, 743, 843, 2),
    (693, 793, 693, 793, 693, 793, 693, 793, 1),
   ```

I generate a new `filled_timestamp` and fill the timestamp at every row for every time step: `filled_timestamp = np.arange(np.datetime64(starttime), np.datetime64(endtime), np.timedelta64(interval))`

Using `idxs = np.in1d(filled_timestamp,raw_timestamp)`, I have all the indices of `filled` which match with time stamps of `raw`. so I can assign `filled_sensor` with the matching data from `raw_sensor`

```
filled_sensor[idxs] = raw_sensor
```

**Q1. Is there a better / faster way to intersect these?**

Now `filled` arrays looks like:

```
>>> filled_timestamp, filled_sensor # shown side-by-side for convenience 
    array([ 
      1 #  ('2009-01-01T18:41:00')  (755, 855, 755, 855, 743, 843, 743, 843, 2),
      2 #  ('2009-01-01T18:42:00')  (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
      3 #  ('2009-01-01T18:43:00')  (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
      4 #  ('2009-01-01T18:44:00')  (693, 793, 693, 793, 693, 793, 693, 793, 1),
      5 #  ('2009-01-01T18:45:00')  (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
      6 #  ('2009-01-01T18:46:00')  (693, 793, 693, 793, 693, 793, 693, 793, 1),
      7 #  ('2009-01-01T18:47:00')  (693, 793, 693, 793, 693, 793, 693, 793, 1)
       ],
          dtype=[('datetime', '<M8[s]')], [('sensorA', '<u4'), ('sensorB', '<u4'), ('sensorC', '<u4'), ('sensorD', '<u4'), ('sensorE', '<u4'), ('sensorF', '<u4'), ('sensorG', '<u4'), ('sensorH', '<u4'), ('signal', '<u4')]
```

**Q2. How can I fill the missing rows with values from the first previous non-empty row? Except column(0 and 3 and last) which is 0 for fills**

In my example above:

Row 2 and 3 would take values from Row 1,

Row 5 would take values from Row 4

End result:

```
>>> filled_timestamp, filled_sensor # shown side-by-side for convenience 
    array([ 
      1 #  ('2009-01-01T18:41:00')  (755, 855, 755, 855, 743, 843, 743, 843, 2),
      2 #  ('2009-01-01T18:42:00')  (0, 855, 755, 0, 743, 843, 743, 843, 0),
      3 #  ('2009-01-01T18:43:00')  (0, 855, 755, 0, 743, 843, 743, 843, 0),
      4 #  ('2009-01-01T18:44:00')  (693, 793, 693, 793, 693, 793, 693, 793, 1),
      5 #  ('2009-01-01T18:45:00')  (0, 793, 693, 0, 693, 793, 693, 793, 0),
      6 #  ('2009-01-01T18:46:00')  (693, 793, 693, 793, 693, 793, 693, 793, 1),
      7 #  ('2009-01-01T18:47:00')  (693, 793, 693, 793, 693, 793, 693, 793, 1)
       ],
          dtype=[('datetime', '<M8[s]')], [('sensorA', '<u4'), ('sensorB', '<u4'), ('sensorC', '<u4'), ('sensorD', '<u4'), ('sensorE', '<u4'), ('sensorF', '<u4'), ('sensorG', '<u4'), ('sensorH', '<u4'), ('signal', '<u4')]
```

Comment: How big is your data?

Comment: data is gigabytes (GB) in size

Comment: Would you consider splitting off the times into a separate array?

Comment: Yes if the dimensions of the arrays won't be changing. Since theres no dependency on the timestamp itself, I can split and recombine later.

Comment: Then you could work with a single t-axis of type timestamp64 and a rows x sensors 2D array without having to have a field array. It would make life a lot easier.

Comment: My current solution will overwrite the timestamps and I don't know how to prevent that without accessing all the columns by name.

Comment: It will also make the computation of arrayB nearly trivial in one go given the vectorized solution I just figured out.

Comment: Do you have a new answer / vectorized solution? I was think of a np.where(false, find argmax(where true but <index of false)) but I'm pretty sure thats horribly inefficient.

Comment: Yes. Writing it up now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144008/discussion-between-encore2097-and-mad-physicist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Intersection**

Your best bet for a fast intersection is probably [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html). It will do a binary search in `filled_timestamp` for the elements of `raw_timestamp`:

```
idx = np.searchsorted(filled_timestamp, raw_timestamp)
```

This will only be accurate if every element of `raw_timestamp` actually occurs in `filled_timestamp` because `np.searchsorted` will return an insertion index regardless.

**Non-vectorized Solution**

You want to set a slice of `filled_sensor` from `idx[n]` to `idx[n + 1]` to the value of `raw_sensor[n]`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
for start, end, row in zip_longest(idx, idx[1:], raw_sensor):
    filled_sensor[start:end] = row
```

I am using `zip_longest` here so that the last value coming from `idx[1:]` would be `None`, making the last slice be equivalent to `filled_sensor[idx[-1]:]` without requiring a special condition.

**Vectorized Solution**

You can create `filled_sensor` in one shot directly from `raw_sensor` if you know which indices to repeat from `raw_sensor`. You can get that information by applying [`np.cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) to `idx` converted to a boolean array:

```
idx_mask = np.zeros(filled_timestamp.shape, np.bool)
idx_mask[idx] = True
```

Basically, we start with a boolean array of the same size as `filled_timestamp` that is `True` (1) wherever an entry from `raw_timestamp` matches. We can convert that to an index in `raw_timestamp` by counting how many total matches have occurred up to that point:

```
indexes = np.cumsum(idx_mask) - 1
```

Keep in mind that `indexes` is an array of integers, not booleans. It will increment whenever a new match is found. The `- 1` converts from count to index because the first match will have a count of 1 instead of 0.

Now you can just make `filled_sensor`:

```
filled_sensor = raw_sensor[indexes]
```

The only possible caveat here is if `filled_sensor[0]` does not come from `raw_sensor[0]`. It will then be replaced with `raw_sensor[-1]`. Given how you construct the times in `filled` based on `raw`, I am not sure can ever even be an issue.

**Example**

Here is an example of the **Intersection** and **Vectorized Solution** steps with the data that you show in your question.

We start with

```
raw_timestamp = np.array(['2009-01-01T18:41:00', 
                          '2009-01-01T18:44:00',
                          '2009-01-01T18:46:00',
                          '2009-01-01T18:47:00',], dtype='datetime64[s]')
raw_sensor = np.array([(755, 855, 755, 855, 743, 843, 743, 843, 2),
                       (693, 793, 693, 793, 693, 793, 693, 793, 1),
                       (755, 855, 755, 855, 743, 843, 743, 843, 2),
                       (693, 793, 693, 793, 693, 793, 693, 793, 1),],
                      dtype=[('sensorA', '<u4'), ('sensorB', '<u4'),
                             ('sensorC', '<u4'), ('sensorD', '<u4'),
                             ('sensorE', '<u4'), ('sensorF', '<u4'),
                             ('sensorG', '<u4'), ('sensorH', '<u4'),
                             ('signal', '<u4')])
```

We can generate `filled_timestamp` as

```
filled_timestamp = np.arange('2009-01-01T18:41:00',
                             '2009-01-01T18:48:00', 60, dtype='datetime64[s]')
```

Which yields, as expected:

```
array(['2009-01-01T18:41:00', '2009-01-01T18:42:00', '2009-01-01T18:43:00',
       '2009-01-01T18:44:00', '2009-01-01T18:45:00', '2009-01-01T18:46:00',
       '2009-01-01T18:47:00'], dtype='datetime64[s]')
```

I have taken a slight liberty with the `dtypes` by making timestamps plain arrays instead of structured arrays, but I think that should make no difference for your purpose.

1. `idx = np.searchsorted(filled_timestamp, raw_timestamp)` yields

   ```
   idx = np.array([0, 3, 5, 6], dtype=np.int)
   ```

   This means that indices `0, 3, 5, 6` in `filled_timestamp` match values from `raw_timestamp`.
2. `idx_mask` then becomes

   ```
   idx_mask = np.array([True, False, False, True, False, True, True], dtype=np.bool)
   ```

   This is basically synonymous with `idx`, except expanded to boolean mask the same size as `filled_timestamp`.
3. Now the tricky part: `indexes = np.cumsum(idx_mask) - 1`:

   ```
   indexes = array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3], dtype=np.int)
   ```

   This can be interpreted as follows: `filled_sensor[0:3]` should come from `raw_sensor[0]`. `filled_sensor[3:5]` should come from `raw_sensor[1]`, `filled_sensor[5]` should come from `raw_sensor[2]`, `filled_sensor[6]` should come from `raw_sensor[3]`.
4. So now we use `indexes` to directly extract the correct elements of `raw_sensor` using `filled_sensor = raw_sensor[indexes]`:

   ```
   np.array([(755, 855, 755, 855, 743, 843, 743, 843, 2),
             (755, 855, 755, 855, 743, 843, 743, 843, 2),
             (755, 855, 755, 855, 743, 843, 743, 843, 2),
             (693, 793, 693, 793, 693, 793, 693, 793, 1),
             (693, 793, 693, 793, 693, 793, 693, 793, 1),
             (755, 855, 755, 855, 743, 843, 743, 843, 2),
             (693, 793, 693, 793, 693, 793, 693, 793, 1)], 
            dtype=[('sensorA', '<u4'), ('sensorB', '<u4'),
                   ('sensorC', '<u4'), ('sensorD', '<u4'),
                   ('sensorE', '<u4'), ('sensorF', '<u4'),
                   ('sensorG', '<u4'), ('sensorH', '<u4'),
                   ('signal', '<u4')])
   ```

Comment: There a step missing to convert the masked T / F into an array of indices where T is the index and F is a 0, then `np.cumsum` works properly. Still working out how to do this as well as masking 0 in the filled fields.

Comment: Sorry, my update shows how to do the intersect faster. All the steps are there now. I suggest you print out all the intermediate steps to see what they do exactly.

Comment: Masking the 0 in the filled in fields is possible with inverting idx to get all the indices of the false values like `filled_sensor[fidx][[0] = 0`, `filled_sensor[fidx][[3] = 0`, `filled_sensor[fidx][[1] = 0`

Comment: I'm assuming `idx` is numerical (not bool mask)  indices in `filled_*`. `idx_mask` is the same size as `filled_*` and has `True` at all `idx` locations. `cumsum` goes along that array and copies the previous value if it encounters `False` (0) and increments by one when it encounters `True` (1). Python and numpy bools are also integers. That creates a list of the indices into `raw_*` that will create `filled_*`. There will be repetitions in this list whenever an entry in `filled_*` does not match one in `raw_*`, just like you are looking for.

Comment: You can just use `~idx_mask` for `fidx`. It's exactly the mask you want.

Comment: Yes, but if you go through the intermediate steps, you see you need to increment past all the false values. Ex: [T, F, F, T, T, F, F, F, T, T] (idx_mask, len 10) => np.cumsum(idx_mask) - 1 => [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4] when it should be [0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 9]

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you mean by "increment past all the false values."

Comment: No, you want what it's giving you. Its the index in `raw` that will go into the corresponding position in `filled`. It's not a trivial concept.

Comment: Put another way, `indexes` should be the same size as `filled`, but if `len(raw) == 5`, it can only contain 0-4.

Comment: Fixed: After `idx_mask[idx] = True`, execute: `idx_mask = np.where(idx_mask, 1, 0) * np.transpose(np.arange(0,idx.size))`

Comment: I don't think that's right. I'll edit my answer with examples as soon as I can. I'm on mobile now.

Comment: `np.where(idx_mask, 1, 0)` should just return `idx_mask` and transpose does nothing to a 1d array.

Comment: When you get to the next true index, you cannot increment by only 1. You need to increment 1 for each false index you passed as well. Does that make sense? Ah thanks: then its `idx_mask = idx_mask * np.arange(0,idx.size)`

Comment: Hmm.. its still not quite right, it breaks on consecutive trues. Solution is to cumsum on zeros, and leave the other indices alone.

Comment: correct solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30488961/fill-zero-values-of-1d-numpy-array-with-last-non-zero-values ... alternatively use pandas as it has forward and backfill functions for time series data ;)

Comment: The second answer there is pretty much exactly what I'm suggesting.

Comment: @encore2097. I've added a concrete example to my answer based on your sample inputs. Unless I am completely misunderstanding what you are looking for, it works exactly as expected.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're getting at. Your method does the copy and the fill at the same time by copying from the original raw array, hences the indices incrementing by 1. I did a copy first and then fill from the same (filled) array because then I can apply the mask at the same time as the fills and do some other ops. Both will work, I do the ops separately for pipeline adaptability and readability.