# Replacing values between two given values in a NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm struggling to find a better way to do the following task:
Looking at the columns of a NumPy array, I need to replace all values between two 1s with a 1.
An example input array would look like this:

```
array([[[1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],
```

and it would have to be converted to this array:

```
array([[[1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],
```

Follow up question: would it be possible to fill the matrix alternately, starting from the top and going down each column (fill the spaces between the first two 1s, then skip till the next 1 and repeat):

```
[[0.],         [[0.],
 [1.],          [1.],
 [0.],          [1.],   
 [0.],          [1.],          
 [1.],          [1.],
 [0.],          [0.],
 [0.],          [0.],
 [1.],   -->    [1.],
 [0.],          [1.],
 [0.],          [1.],
 [0.],          [1.],
 [1.],          [1.], 
 [0.],          [0.],
 [0.],          [0.], 
 [1.]],         [1.]],
```

I can already implement this using for loops and conditionals, but the code is much too slow because of the size of the arrays that I'm working with.

Comment: For the follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60049171/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get pretty close using `np.maximum.accumulate`.

Edit: Here's the correct solution (a little ugly because of the extra axis).

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([[[1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
...         [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
...         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
...         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
...         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
...         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
...         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
...         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
...         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
...         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
...         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
...         [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
...         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
...         [1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
...         [1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]])
>>> up = np.maximum.accumulate(arr, axis=1)
>>> down = np.flip(np.maximum.accumulate(np.flip(arr, axis=1), axis=1), axis=1)
>>> np.logical_and(up, down).astype(int)
array([[[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```