# How to fill numpy array between two specific values

Tags: python, numpy

I have to fill np array in row 2 with values from row 0.
Array looks like that:

```
[[3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9. 8. 7. 6.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Finally it should looks like bellow

```
[[3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9. 8. 7. 6.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [5. 5. 5. 8. 8. 8. 6. 6. 6. 6.]]
```

That means:

First row determine points of change. From beginning of row 3 to place where first value "1" in row 2, the row 3 should have value from row 0 where in row two occurs first value "1" and so on..

There is something similar but not exactly what i need.
[Fill values in numpy array that are between a certain value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60049171/fill-values-in-numpy-array-that-are-between-a-certain-value)

Do you know how to do it without iterate over columns?

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the logic, i.e. please include a version of the code that iterates over the columns.

Comment: Can you please provide that data as valid code?

Comment: If the 1s there are irregularly spaced, then I'm not convinced there is a way to do it without iterating.

Comment: @TimRoberts But you can let NumPy do the iterating.

Comment: Can the last value in the middle row be 1? If yes, what shall the result be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### using indexing

You can get the negative indices at the positions of the 1s (and the last), then backfill using a reverse cumulated minimum:

```
idx = np.minimum.accumulate(np.where(a[1], np.arange(-a.shape[1], 0), -1)[::-1])[::-1]
# array([-8, -8, -8, -5, -5, -5, -1, -1, -1, -1])
a[2] = a[0, idx]
```

Step by step intermediates to construct `idx` (where `_` denote the previous command):

```
np.arange(-a.shape[1], 0)
# array([-10,  -9,  -8,  -7,  -6,  -5,  -4,  -3,  -2,  -1])

np.where(a[1], _, -1)
# array([-1, -1, -8, -1, -1, -5, -1, -1, -1, -1])

np.minimum.accumulate(_[::-1])[::-1]
# array([-8, -8, -8, -5, -5, -5, -1, -1, -1, -1])
```

Same logic with positive indexing:

```
idx = np.minimum.accumulate(
    np.where(a[1], np.arange(a.shape[1]), a.shape[1] - 1)[::-1]
)[::-1]

a[2] = a[0, idx]
```

Intermediates:

```
np.arange(a.shape[1])
# array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

np.where(a[1], _, a.shape[1]-1)
# array([9, 9, 2, 9, 9, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9])

np.minimum.accumulate(_[::-1])[::-1]
# array([2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9])
```

##### using [`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

Here we get the indices of the 1s (and the last position), compute the number of items to repeat

```
idx = np.where(np.r_[a[1, :-1], 1])[0]
# array([2, 5, 9])

a[2] = np.repeat(a[0, idx], np.diff(np.r_[-1, idx]))
# np.repeat([5, 8, 6], [3, 3, 4])
```

##### using [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas)'s [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.bfill.html):

```
import pandas as pd

a[2] = pd.Series(a[0]).where(np.r_[a[1, :-1]==1, True]).bfill()
```

##### Output

```
array([[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 7, 6],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [5, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8, 6, 6, 6, 6]])
```

Comment: Solution with np.repeat is ok. It seems to work fine.  I will use it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 8., 7., 6.],
 [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
 [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])

lastitem = arr[1,-1]
arr[1, -1] = 1.

vals = arr[0, arr[1].astype(bool)][::-1]
idxs = arr[1].astype(int)[::-1].cumsum() - 1

arr[1, -1] = lastitem
arr[2] = vals[idxs][::-1]

print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[[3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9. 8. 7. 6.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [5. 5. 5. 8. 8. 8. 6. 6. 6. 6.]]
```

Basic idea is to use `arr[1]` first as boolean array to extract the items of `arr[0]` which will be really used to `vals`. `vals` is reversed.

Then `arr[1]` is converted to `int`, reversed, cumulative sum applied and adjusted so that it finally is an array of indexes into `vals` named `idxs`.

Last step is to convert the indexes into actual values and set `arr[2]` accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Use assignment:

```
arr[2] = np.r_[arr[0,arr[1]==1], arr[0,-1]][np.roll(arr[1],1).cumsum(dtype=int)]
arr 

array([[3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 8., 7., 6.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [5., 5., 5., 8., 8., 8., 6., 6., 6., 6.]])
```

Comment: If you delete another space character, it'll even fit PEP 8's 79 characters line limit.

Comment: Fails if I change the middle row's last value to 1.

Comment: @KellyBundy the last value cannot be 1. ie how will that be *a point of change*?. Try any other place besides the last value

Comment: @KellyBundy also a 1 in the end is alittle ambiguous. ie in the example above, what would be the output if there was a 1 at the end?

Comment: Maybe. I've asked them.

Comment: First I tried your solution because one line code. I tested a little bit and It is not working correctly. Look what will by if arr[1] = [0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1.] . I got arr like that: [[ 3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9. 12.  7.  2.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 6.  6.  8.  8. 12. 12.  2.  2.  2.  2.]]