# Optimize torch function which replace zero elements with first non-zero element encountered

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to rewrite this function to improve time performances. I would like to use only torch primary functions and avoid using any for loops. The following function substitutes the zero elements with the first non-zero elements in order:

Unoptimized code:

```
last_val=0
for i in range(t.shape[0]-1, -1, -1):
   if (t[i] > 0):
      last_val = t[i]
   else:
      t[i] = last_val
```

Input:

```
t = torch.tensor([0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 7, 0, 8, 9])
```

Expected output:

```
t = torch.tensor([5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9])
```

Comment: What do you mean "without using a for loop"?
Do you want a while loop? And maybe more important: Why do you want that?

Comment: No, I want to use the the torch primary functions to improve time performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can follow the approach from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30489294/7395592), which fills succeeding zeros in a NumPy array. To account for the differences between your question and this referenced answer, we need to make two major changes:

1. As we want to fill preceding zeros rather than succeeding zeros, we need to reverse our input first. Then, in the end, we need to reverse our result.
2. As your question is about PyTorch, we need to replace all NumPy functions with their PyTorch equivalents.

This results in

```py
import torch

t = torch.tensor([0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 7, 0, 8, 9])

t_reversed = t.flip(0)  # Reverse order of values
indexes = torch.arange(len(t_reversed))
indexes[t_reversed == 0] = 0
indexes = indexes.cummax(0).values
result = t_reversed[indexes].flip(0)

print(result)
# >>> tensor([5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9])
```

Here, the `indexes` tensor represents indexes of the elements we are interested in. We proceed as follows:

1. At the beginning, each value in `indexes` corresponds to its actual index (`indexes = torch.arange(len(t_reversed))`).
2. Only the indexes of the non-zero elements in the given, reversed tensor are kept and the others are zeroed out (`indexes[t_reversed == 0] = 0`).
3. The indexes are propagated to the right with the cumulative maximum function (`indexes.cummax(0).values`). The cumulative maximum stores in each tensor location the largest number that it has seen, so far, from left to right. We can do this with the indexes because they are monotonically increasing (i.e. get bigger and bigger from left to right), so each zero is replaced with the preceding non-zero index, until the next non-zero index (which is guaranteed to be bigger) is reached. Although it might be tempting, we cannot do so directly with the values in our given tensor, since we have no such guarantee on monotonicity there. As a result, `indexes` now holds the indexes of the values that have to be filled in the corresponding positions.
4. We use `indexes` as an index list to access the values in our given, reversed tensor (`t_reversed[indexes]`), so that in every position, the index is replaced by the actual value.
5. Finally, we reverse the values into their original order (`flip(0)`).

#### One-liner solution

If we are extra crazy, we can even put this into a (slightly adjusted) one-liner:

```py
from torch import arange, tensor, where
t = tensor([0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 7, 0, 8, 9])
print(t.flip(0)[where(t.flip(0) == 0, 0, arange(len(t))).cummax(0).values].flip(0))
# >>> tensor([5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9])
```

Using the [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions), we can spare one more flip here:

```py
print((r := t.flip(0))[where(r == 0, 0, arange(len(t))).cummax(0).values].flip(0))
# >>> tensor([5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9])
```

Answer (score 2):

Updated

```
import numpy as np

t = np.array([0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 7, 0, 8, 9])

non_zero_indices = np.nonzero(t)

if len(non_zero_indices[0]) > 0:
    first_non_zero_value = t[non_zero_indices][0]

    for i in range(len(t)):
        if t[i] == 0:
            t[i] = first_non_zero_value

print(t)
```

Comment: This does not help me since it requires anyhow to iterate with a for loop over the tensor dimension