# Most efficient way to forward-fill NaN values in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, pandas, numpy

### Example Problem

As a simple example, consider the numpy array `arr` as defined below:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[5, np.nan, np.nan, 7, 2],
                [3, np.nan, 1, 8, np.nan],
                [4, 9, 6, np.nan, np.nan]])
```

where `arr` looks like this in console output:

```
array([[  5.,  nan,  nan,   7.,   2.],
       [  3.,  nan,   1.,   8.,  nan],
       [  4.,   9.,   6.,  nan,  nan]])
```

I would now like to row-wise 'forward-fill' the `nan` values in array `arr`. By that I mean replacing each `nan` value with the nearest valid value from the left. The desired result would look like this:

```
array([[  5.,   5.,   5.,  7.,  2.],
       [  3.,   3.,   1.,  8.,  8.],
       [  4.,   9.,   6.,  6.,  6.]])
```

---

### Tried thus far

I've tried using for-loops:

```
for row_idx in range(arr.shape[0]):
    for col_idx in range(arr.shape[1]):
        if np.isnan(arr[row_idx][col_idx]):
            arr[row_idx][col_idx] = arr[row_idx][col_idx - 1]
```

I've also tried using a pandas dataframe as an intermediate step (since pandas dataframes have a very neat built-in method for forward-filling):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
df.fillna(method='ffill', axis=1, inplace=True)
arr = df.as_matrix()
```

Both of the above strategies produce the desired result, but I keep on wondering: wouldn't a strategy that uses only numpy vectorized operations be the most efficient one?

---

### Summary

Is there another more efficient way to 'forward-fill' `nan` values in numpy arrays? (e.g. by using numpy vectorized operations)

---

## Update: Solutions Comparison

I've tried to time all solutions thus far. This was my setup script:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def random_array():
    choices = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, np.nan]
    out = np.random.choice(choices, size=(1000, 10))
    return out

def loops_fill(arr):
    out = arr.copy()
    for row_idx in range(out.shape[0]):
        for col_idx in range(1, out.shape[1]):
            if np.isnan(out[row_idx, col_idx]):
                out[row_idx, col_idx] = out[row_idx, col_idx - 1]
    return out

@nb.jit
def numba_loops_fill(arr):
    '''Numba decorator solution provided by shx2.'''
    out = arr.copy()
    for row_idx in range(out.shape[0]):
        for col_idx in range(1, out.shape[1]):
            if np.isnan(out[row_idx, col_idx]):
                out[row_idx, col_idx] = out[row_idx, col_idx - 1]
    return out

def pandas_fill(arr):
    df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
    df.fillna(method='ffill', axis=1, inplace=True)
    out = df.as_matrix()
    return out

def numpy_fill(arr):
    '''Solution provided by Divakar.'''
    mask = np.isnan(arr)
    idx = np.where(~mask,np.arange(mask.shape[1]),0)
    np.maximum.accumulate(idx,axis=1, out=idx)
    out = arr[np.arange(idx.shape[0])[:,None], idx]
    return out
```

followed by this console input:

```
%timeit -n 1000 loops_fill(random_array())
%timeit -n 1000 numba_loops_fill(random_array())
%timeit -n 1000 pandas_fill(random_array())
%timeit -n 1000 numpy_fill(random_array())
```

resulting in this console output:

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 9.64 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 377 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 455 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 351 µs per loop
```

Comment: what should happen if the first element in a row is `nan`?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen In this case, pandas leaves the `NaN` untouched. I would assume the OP wants the same behavior for consistency.

Comment: [Fill zero values of 1d numpy array with last nonzero values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30488961/fill-zero-values-of-1d-numpy-array-with-last-non-zero-values). You might find this useful.

Comment: Ah, good question. In my use cases the first column of the input array is not supposed to ever contain any `nan` values. So it's okay for me when the code (upon encounter of a `nan` in the first column) either raises an exception or leaves that `nan` in place.

Comment: I believe pandas is actually using vectorized operations on the original underlying numpy array. The only overhead of your second option is wrapping the array with a dataframe and unwrapping it again, which is probably quite modest for large matrices.

Comment: BTW, there is not even a need to call `as_matrix()`: the original `arr` is changed.

Comment: @DYZ  Just tested it, and the original `arr` is indeed updated like you said. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: One small tip: `arr[i,j]` is better and faster than `arr[i][j]`.

Comment: @shx2 Noted, thanks.

Comment: I am looking for the solution for 3D array, for 2D ones the dumbest way is converting it to df first, then using fillna.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Here's one approach  -

```
mask = np.isnan(arr)
idx = np.where(~mask,np.arange(mask.shape[1]),0)
np.maximum.accumulate(idx,axis=1, out=idx)
out = arr[np.arange(idx.shape[0])[:,None], idx]
```

If you don't want to create another array and just fill the NaNs in `arr` itself, replace the last step with this -

```
arr[mask] = arr[np.nonzero(mask)[0], idx[mask]]
```

Sample input, output -

```
In [179]: arr
Out[179]: 
array([[  5.,  nan,  nan,   7.,   2.,   6.,   5.],
       [  3.,  nan,   1.,   8.,  nan,   5.,  nan],
       [  4.,   9.,   6.,  nan,  nan,  nan,   7.]])

In [180]: out
Out[180]: 
array([[ 5.,  5.,  5.,  7.,  2.,  6.,  5.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  1.,  8.,  8.,  5.,  5.],
       [ 4.,  9.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  7.]])
```

Comment: A vectorized numpy-only solution, nice. Thanks! This solution indeed appears to be faster than the loop-based and pandas-based solutions (see timings in updated question).

Comment: @Xukrao Yeah I just saw those, thanks for adding in those timing results! Good to see some speedups there!

Comment: How do you adapt this solution to the case arr is a *one dimensional* numpy array? Like `numpy.array([0.83, 0.83, 0.83, 0.83,  nan,  nan,  nan])`?

Comment: @user189035 replace `mask.shape[1]` with `mask.size` and remove `axis=1` and replace the last line with `out = arr[idx]`

Comment: I had a case where I built a second matrix for what I wanted to forward fill with. On the last line I just replaced `arr` with `fillMatrix`. My case was reducing resolution on time-series data, so I forward filled with the most recent entry

Comment: @Xukrao this does not work for a lot of cases. See my answer, I put an example where it fails!

Answer (score 8):

I liked Divakar's answer on pure numpy.
Here's a generalized function for n-dimensional arrays:

```
def np_ffill(arr, axis):
    idx_shape = tuple([slice(None)] + [np.newaxis] * (len(arr.shape) - axis - 1))
    idx = np.where(~np.isnan(arr), np.arange(arr.shape[axis])[idx_shape], 0)
    np.maximum.accumulate(idx, axis=axis, out=idx)
    slc = [np.arange(k)[tuple([slice(None) if dim==i else np.newaxis
        for dim in range(len(arr.shape))])]
        for i, k in enumerate(arr.shape)]
    slc[axis] = idx
    return arr[tuple(slc)]
```

AFIK pandas can only work with two dimensions, despite having multi-index to make up for it. The only way to accomplish this would be to flatten a DataFrame, unstack desired level, restack, and finally reshape as original. This unstacking/restacking/reshaping, with the pandas sorting involved, is just unnecessary overhead to achieve the same result.

Testing:

```
def random_array(shape):
    choices = [1, 2, 3, 4, np.nan]
    out = np.random.choice(choices, size=shape)
    return out

ra = random_array((2, 4, 8))
print('arr')
print(ra)
print('\nffull')
print(np_ffill(ra, 1))
raise SystemExit
```

Output:

```
arr
[[[ 3. nan  4.  1.  4.  2.  2.  3.]
  [ 2. nan  1.  3. nan  4.  4.  3.]
  [ 3.  2. nan  4. nan nan  3.  4.]
  [ 2.  2.  2. nan  1.  1. nan  2.]]

 [[ 2.  3.  2. nan  3.  3.  3.  3.]
  [ 3.  3.  1.  4.  1.  4.  1. nan]
  [ 4.  2. nan  4.  4.  3. nan  4.]
  [ 2.  4.  2.  1.  4.  1.  3. nan]]]

ffull
[[[ 3. nan  4.  1.  4.  2.  2.  3.]
  [ 2. nan  1.  3.  4.  4.  4.  3.]
  [ 3.  2.  1.  4.  4.  4.  3.  4.]
  [ 2.  2.  2.  4.  1.  1.  3.  2.]]

 [[ 2.  3.  2. nan  3.  3.  3.  3.]
  [ 3.  3.  1.  4.  1.  4.  1.  3.]
  [ 4.  2.  1.  4.  4.  3.  1.  4.]
  [ 2.  4.  2.  1.  4.  1.  3.  4.]]]
```

Answer (score 7):

**Update**: As pointed out by financial_physician in the comments, my initially proposed solution can simply be exchanged with `ffill` on the reversed array and then reversing the result. There is no relevant performance loss. My initial solution seems to be 2% or 3% faster according to `%timeit`. I updated the code example below but left my initial text as it was.

---

For those that came here looking for the backward-fill of NaN values, I modified [the solution provided by Divakar above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41191127/356463) to do exactly that. The trick is that you have to do the accumulation on the reversed array using the minimum except for the maximum.

Here is the code:

```py
# ffill along axis 1, as provided in the answer by Divakar
def ffill(arr):
    mask = np.isnan(arr)
    idx = np.where(~mask, np.arange(mask.shape[1]), 0)
    np.maximum.accumulate(idx, axis=1, out=idx)
    out = arr[np.arange(idx.shape[0])[:,None], idx]
    return out

# Simple solution for bfill provided by financial_physician in comment below
def bfill(arr): 
    return ffill(arr[:, ::-1])[:, ::-1]

# My outdated modification of Divakar's answer to do a backward-fill
def bfill_old(arr):
    mask = np.isnan(arr)
    idx = np.where(~mask, np.arange(mask.shape[1]), mask.shape[1] - 1)
    idx = np.minimum.accumulate(idx[:, ::-1], axis=1)[:, ::-1]
    out = arr[np.arange(idx.shape[0])[:,None], idx]
    return out


# Test both functions
arr = np.array([[5, np.nan, np.nan, 7, 2],
                [3, np.nan, 1, 8, np.nan],
                [4, 9, 6, np.nan, np.nan]])
print('Array:')
print(arr)

print('\nffill')
print(ffill(arr))

print('\nbfill')
print(bfill(arr))
```

Output:

```
Array:
[[ 5. nan nan  7.  2.]
 [ 3. nan  1.  8. nan]
 [ 4.  9.  6. nan nan]]

ffill
[[5. 5. 5. 7. 2.]
 [3. 3. 1. 8. 8.]
 [4. 9. 6. 6. 6.]]

bfill
[[ 5.  7.  7.  7.  2.]
 [ 3.  1.  1.  8. nan]
 [ 4.  9.  6. nan nan]]
```

Edit: Update according to comment of MS_

Comment: `idx = np.where(~mask, np.arange(mask.shape[1]), mask.shape[0] + 1)` in `bfill` should be `idx = np.where(~mask, np.arange(mask.shape[1]), mask.shape[1] - 1)`

Comment: Isn't flipping `O(n)` and you're doing it twice so wouldn't flipping, using forward fill, and then unflipping, be just as fast as your bfill method with the original array?

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed a very good point. I did time your solution and mine using `%%timeit` and there is only a negligible but consistent difference, 10.3 µs (your solution) vs 9.95 µs (my solution). I will update my response accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

[bottleneck push function](https://kwgoodman.github.io/bottleneck-doc/reference.html#bottleneck.push) is a good option to forward fill. It's normally used internally in packages like Xarray, it should be faster than other alternatives and the package also has a set of [benchmarks](https://kwgoodman.github.io/bottleneck-doc/intro.html#benchmark).

Example:

```py
import numpy as np

from bottleneck import push

a = np.array(
    [
        [1, np.nan, 3],
        [np.nan, 3, 2],
        [2, np.nan, np.nan]
    ]
)
push(a, axis=0)
array([[ 1., nan,  3.],
       [ 1.,  3.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  2.]])
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/). This should give a significant speedup:

```
import numba
@numba.jit
def loops_fill(arr):
    ...
```

Comment: Would Numba only speed up the loops-based solution? Or would it speed up the other solutions as well?

Comment: It is good for loops. It would not speed up functions implemented in numpy/pandas.

Comment: Thanks! I've included this solution in the timing comparison (see updated question). It looks like the addition of the numba decorator to the loop-based solution reduces its runtime by one order of magnitude.

Answer (score 3):

I like Divakar's answer, but it doesn't work for an edge case where a row starts with np.nan, like the `arr` below

```
arr = np.array([[9, np.nan, 4, np.nan, 6, 6, 7, 2, 3, np.nan],
[ np.nan, 5, 5, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1, np.nan, 10]])
```

The output using Divakar's code would be:

```
[[ 9.  9.  4.  4.  6.  6.  7.  2.  3.  3.]
 [nan  4.  5.  6.  5.  3.  2.  1.  1. 10.]]
```

Divakar's code can be simplified a bit, and the simplified version solves this issue at the same time:

```
arr[np.isnan(arr)] = arr[np.nonzero(np.isnan(arr))[0], np.nonzero(np.isnan(arr))[1]-1]
```

In case of several `np.nan`s in a row (either in the beginning or in the middle), just repeat this operation several times. For instance, if the array has 5 consecutive `np.nan`s, the following code will "forward fill" all of them with the number before these `np.nan`s:

```
for i in range(0, 5):
   value[np.isnan(value)] = value[np.nonzero(np.isnan(value))[0], np.nonzero(np.isnan(value))[1]-1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use bottleneck module, it comes along with pandas or numpy module so no need to separately install.

Below code should give you desired result.

```
import bottleneck as bn
bn.push(arr,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who are interested in the problem of having leading `np.nan` after foward-filling, the following works:

```
mask = np.isnan(arr)
first_non_zero_idx = (~mask!=0).argmax(axis=1) #Get indices of first non-zero values
arr = [ np.hstack([
             [arr[i,first_nonzero]]*(first_nonzero), 
             arr[i,first_nonzero:]])
             for i, first_nonzero in enumerate(first_non_zero_idx) ]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the purpose of this code. What exactly do you mean by 'problem of having leading np.nan after forward-filling'?

Comment: In the example array in the beginning of the threat, each entry begins with a non nan. Some people might find themselves dealing with a data set that requires backward filling because forward filling will leave the first entries untouched. So I thought it might be useful to present a solution in this threat.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use Pandas/ xarray: Let axis be the direction you wish to ffill/bfill over, as shown below,

```
xr.DataArray(arr).ffill(f'dim_{axis}').values
xr.DataArray(arr).bfill(f'dim_{axis}').values
```

More information:
http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.ffill.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html

Answer (score 0):

unless I miss something, the solutions does not works on any example:

```
arr  = np.array([[ 3.],
 [ 8.],
 [np.nan],
 [ 7.],
 [np.nan],
 [ 1.],
 [np.nan],
 [ 3.],
 [ 8.],
 [ 8.]])
print("A:::: \n", arr)

print("numpy_fill::: \n ",  numpy_fill(arr))
print("loop_fill",  loops_fill(arr))

A:::: 
 [[ 3.]
 [ 8.]
 [nan]
 [ 7.]
 [nan]
 [ 1.]
 [nan]
 [ 3.]
 [ 8.]
 [ 8.]]
numpy_fill::: 
  [[ 3.]
 [ 8.]
 [nan]
 [ 7.]
 [nan]
 [ 1.]
 [nan]
 [ 3.]
 [ 8.]
 [ 8.]]
loop_fill [[ 3.]
 [ 8.]
 [nan]
 [ 7.]
 [nan]
 [ 1.]
 [nan]
 [ 3.]
 [ 8.]
 [ 8.]]

Comments ??
```

Answer (score 0):

Minor improvement of of [RichieV generalized pure numpy solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60941040/15330539) with axis selection and 'backward' support

```py
def _np_fill_(arr, axis=-1, fill_dir='f'):
    """Base function for np_fill, np_ffill, np_bfill."""
    if axis < 0:
        axis = len(arr.shape) + axis
    
    if fill_dir.lower() in ['b', 'backward']:
        dir_change = tuple([*[slice(None)]*axis, slice(None, None, -1)])
        return np_ffill(arr[dir_change])[dir_change]
    elif fill_dir.lower() not in ['f', 'forward']:
        raise KeyError(f"fill_dir must be one of: 'b', 'backward', 'f', 'forward'. Got: {fill_dir}")
    
    idx_shape = tuple([slice(None)] + [np.newaxis] * (len(arr.shape) - axis - 1))
    idx = np.where(~np.isnan(arr), np.arange(arr.shape[axis])[idx_shape], 0)
    np.maximum.accumulate(idx, axis=axis, out=idx)
    slc = [np.arange(k)[tuple([slice(None) if dim==i else np.newaxis
        for dim in range(len(arr.shape))])]
        for i, k in enumerate(arr.shape)]
    slc[axis] = idx
    return arr[tuple(slc)]

def np_fill(arr, axis=-1, fill_dir='f'):
    """General fill function which supports multiple filling steps. I.e.: 
    fill_dir=['f', 'b'] or fill_dir=['b', 'f']"""
    if isinstance(fill_dir, (tuple, list, np.ndarray)):
        for i in fill_dir:
            arr = _np_fill_(arr, axis=axis, fill_dir=i)
    else:
        arr = _np_fill_(arr, axis=axis, fill_dir=fill_dir)
    return arr

def np_ffill(arr, axis=-1):
    return np_fill(arr, axis=axis, fill_dir='forward')

def np_bfill(arr, axis=-1):
    return np_fill(arr, axis=axis, fill_dir='backward')
```

Answer (score -1):

I used *np.nan_to_num*
Example:

```
data = np.nan_to_num(data, data.mean())
```

Reference : [Numpy document](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html)