# Forward Fill Pandas Dataframe Horizontally (along rows) without forward filling last value in each row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas dataframe that I want to forward fill HORIZONTALLY but I don't want to forward fill past the last entry in each row. This is time series pricing data on products where some have been discontinued so I dont want the last value recorded to be forward filled to current.

```
FWDFILL.apply(lambda series: series.iloc[:,series.last_valid_index()].ffill(axis=1))
```

^The code I have included does what I want but it does it VERTICALLY. This could maybe help people as a starting point.

```
>>> print(FWDFILL)

1      1     NaN     NaN     2     NaN  
2     NaN     1      NaN     5     NaN  
3     NaN     3       1     NaN    NaN  
4     NaN    NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN  
5     NaN     5      NaN    NaN     1
```

Desired Output:

```
1      1      1      1     2     NaN  
2     NaN     1      1     5     NaN  
3     NaN     3      1    NaN    NaN  
4     NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN  
5     NaN     5      5     5      1
```

Comment: `df.ffill(axis=1)`?

Answer (score 4):

IIUC, you need to `apply` with `axis=1`, so you are applying to dataframe rows instead of dataframe columns.

```
df.apply(lambda x: x[:x.last_valid_index()].ffill(), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
     1    2    3    4    5
0                         
1  1.0  1.0  1.0  2.0  NaN
2  NaN  1.0  1.0  5.0  NaN
3  NaN  3.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  5.0  5.0  5.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 4):

Usage of `bfill` and `ffill`

```
s1=df.ffill(1)
s2=df.bfill(1)
df=df.mask(s1.notnull()&s2.notnull(),s1)
df
Out[222]: 
     1    2    3    4    5
1  1.0  1.0  1.0  2.0  NaN
2  NaN  1.0  1.0  5.0  NaN
3  NaN  3.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  5.0  5.0  5.0  1.0
```

Or just using `interpolate`

```
df.mask(df.interpolate(axis=1,limit_area='inside').notnull(),df.ffill(1))
Out[226]: 
     1    2    3    4    5
1  1.0  1.0  1.0  2.0  NaN
2  NaN  1.0  1.0  5.0  NaN
3  NaN  3.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  5.0  5.0  5.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `numpy` to find the last valid indices and mask your `ffill`.  This allows you to use the vectorized `ffill` and then a vectorized mask.

---

```
u = df.values
m = (~np.isnan(u)).cumsum(1).argmax(1)
df.ffill(1).mask(np.arange(df.shape[0]) > m[:, None])
```

```
     0    1    2    3    4
0  1.0  1.0  1.0  2.0  NaN
1  NaN  1.0  1.0  5.0  NaN
2  NaN  3.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  5.0  5.0  5.0  1.0
```

---

***Info***

```
>>> np.arange(df.shape[0]) > m[:, None]
array([[False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Little modification to - [`Most efficient way to forward-fill NaN values in numpy array`'s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41191127/), solves it here -

```
def ffillrows_stoplast(arr):
    # Identical to earlier solution of forward-filling
    mask = np.isnan(arr)
    idx = np.where(~mask,np.arange(mask.shape[1]),0)
    idx_acc = np.maximum.accumulate(idx,axis=1)
    out = arr[np.arange(idx.shape[0])[:,None], idx_acc]

    # Perform flipped index accumulation to get trailing NaNs mask and
    # accordingly assign NaNs there
    out[np.maximum.accumulate(idx[:,::-1],axis=1)[:,::-1]==0] = np.nan
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [121]: df
Out[121]: 
     A    B    C    D    E
1  1.0  NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN
2  NaN  1.0  NaN  5.0  NaN
3  NaN  3.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  5.0  NaN  NaN  1.0

In [122]: out = ffillrows_stoplast(df.to_numpy())

In [123]: pd.DataFrame(out,columns=df.columns,index=df.index)
Out[123]: 
     A    B    C    D    E
1  1.0  1.0  1.0  2.0  NaN
2  NaN  1.0  1.0  5.0  NaN
3  NaN  3.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  5.0  5.0  5.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think of using `where` on `ffill` to flip back to `NaN` those got ignored on `bfill`

```
df.ffill(1).where(df.bfill(1).notna())    

Out[1623]:
     a    b    c    d    e
1  1.0  1.0  1.0  2.0  NaN
2  NaN  1.0  1.0  5.0  NaN
3  NaN  3.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  5.0  5.0  5.0  1.0
```