# Fill nan in numpy array

Tags: numpy

Is there a straight forward way of filling nan values in a numpy array when the left and right non nan values match?

For example, if I have an array that has False, False , NaN, NaN, False,  I want the NaN values to also be False.  If the left and right values do not match, I want it to keep the NaN

Comment: Try to use numpy.isnan() function

Comment: `False` is a boolean.  `nan` us a float.

Comment: If you check …. a = np.array([np.NaN, False, np.NaN, True]) … will yield …. array([nan,  0., nan,  1.]) …. which apparently you don't have.  What is your actual array?

Comment: What's the array's dtype and shape?  And in the result?

Answer (score 2):

Your first task is to reliably identify the `np.nan` elements.  Because it's  a unique float value, testing isn't trivail.  `np.isnan` is the best `numpy` tool.

To mix boolean and float (`np.nan`) you have to use object dtype:

```
In [68]: arr = np.array([False, False, np.nan, np.nan, False],object)                                        
In [69]: arr                                                                                                 
Out[69]: array([False, False, nan, nan, False], dtype=object)
```

converting to float changes the False to 0 (and True to 1):

```
In [70]: arr.astype(float)                                                                                   
Out[70]: array([ 0.,  0., nan, nan,  0.])
```

`np.isnan` is a good test for `nan`, but it only works on floats:

```
In [71]: np.isnan(arr)                                                                                       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-25d2f1dae78d> in <module>
----> 1 np.isnan(arr)

TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

In [72]: np.isnan(arr.astype(float))                                                                         
Out[72]: array([False, False,  True,  True, False])
```

You could test the object array (or a list) with a helper function and a list comprehension:

```
In [73]: def foo(x): 
    ...:     try: 
    ...:         return np.isnan(x) 
    ...:     except TypeError: 
    ...:         return x 
    ...:                                                                                                     
In [74]: [foo(x) for x in arr]                                                                               
Out[74]: [False, False, True, True, False]
```

Having reliably identified the `nan` values, you can then apply the before/after logic.  I'm not sure if it's easier with lists or array (your logic isn't entirely clear).

Answer (score 0):

See also [Most efficient way to forward-fill NaN values in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41190852/most-efficient-way-to-forward-fill-nan-values-in-numpy-array)

Pandas offers the `interpolate` method on data frames. You could use it like this:

```
interpolate(limit_direction='both').to_numpy().flatten()
```

A much more specialized method is given below, it allows controlling the B-Spline interpolation parameters, extrapolation and smoothing:

https://github.com/DomTomCat/signalProcessing/blob/main/interpolateNonFiniteValues.py