# Numpy: Fill NaN with values from previous row

Tags: python, numpy

I need to replace NaN with values from the previous row except for the first row where NaN values are replaced with zero. What would be the most efficient solution?

Sample input, output -

```
In [179]: arr
Out[179]: 
array([[  5.,  nan,  nan,   7.,   2.,   6.,   5.],
       [  3.,  nan,   1.,   8.,  nan,   5.,  nan],
       [  4.,   9.,   6.,  nan,  nan,  nan,   7.]])

In [180]: out
Out[180]: 
array([[ 5.,  0,  0.,  7.,  2.,  6.,  5.],
       [ 3.,  0,  1.,  8.,  2.,  5.,  5.],
       [ 4.,  9.,  6.,  8.,  2.,  6.,  7.]])
```

Comment: The output does not match your description. Where there is a `nan` above another `nan` you actually do not want the value from the row above, but the first non-`nan` value above it - columnwise. So, which one is it?

Answer (score 4):

(**EDIT** to include a (partially?) vectorized approach)

(**EDIT2** to include some timings)

The simplest solution matching your required input/output is by looping through the rows:

```
import numpy as np


def ffill_loop(arr, fill=0):
    mask = np.isnan(arr[0])
    arr[0][mask] = fill
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        mask = np.isnan(arr[i])
        arr[i][mask] = arr[i - 1][mask]
    return arr


print(ffill_loop(arr.copy()))
# [[5. 0. 0. 7. 2. 6. 5.]
#  [3. 0. 1. 8. 2. 5. 5.]
#  [4. 9. 6. 8. 2. 5. 7.]]
```

---

You could also use a vectorized approach which may come faster for larger inputs (the fewer the `nan` below each other, the better):

```
import numpy as np


def ffill_roll(arr, fill=0, axis=0):
    mask = np.isnan(arr)
    replaces = np.roll(arr, 1, axis)
    slicing = tuple(0 if i == axis else slice(None) for i in range(arr.ndim))
    replaces[slicing] = fill
    while np.count_nonzero(mask) > 0:
        arr[mask] = replaces[mask]
        mask = np.isnan(arr)
        replaces = np.roll(replaces, 1, axis)
    return arr


print(ffill_roll(arr.copy()))
# [[5. 0. 0. 7. 2. 6. 5.]
#  [3. 0. 1. 8. 2. 5. 5.]
#  [4. 9. 6. 8. 2. 5. 7.]]
```

---

Timing these function one would get (including the loop-less solution proposed in [@Divakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62039482/5218354)):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import nan


funcs = ffill_loop, ffill_roll, ffill_cols
sep = ' ' * 4
print(f'{"shape":15s}', end=sep)
for func in funcs:
    print(f'{func.__name__:>15s}', end=sep)
print()
for n in (1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 2000):
    k = l = n
    arr = np.array([[  5.,  nan,  nan,   7.,   2.,   6.,   5.] * k,
        [  3.,  nan,   1.,   8.,  nan,   5.,  nan] * k,
        [  4.,   9.,   6.,  nan,  nan,  nan,   7.] * k] * l)
    print(f'{arr.shape!s:15s}', end=sep)
    for func in funcs:
        result = %timeit -q -o func(arr.copy())
        print(f'{result.best * 1e3:12.3f} ms', end=sep)
    print()
```

```
shape                   ffill_loop         ffill_roll         ffill_cols    
(3, 7)                    0.009 ms           0.063 ms           0.026 ms    
(15, 35)                  0.043 ms           0.074 ms           0.034 ms    
(30, 70)                  0.092 ms           0.098 ms           0.055 ms    
(150, 350)                0.783 ms           0.939 ms           0.786 ms    
(300, 700)                2.409 ms           4.060 ms           3.829 ms    
(1500, 3500)             49.447 ms         105.379 ms         169.649 ms    
(3000, 7000)            169.799 ms         340.548 ms         759.854 ms    
(6000, 14000)           656.982 ms        1369.651 ms        1610.094 ms
```

Indicating that `ffill_loop()` is actually the fastest for the given inputs most of the times. Instead `ffill_cols()` gets progressively to be the slowest approach as the input size increases.

Comment: [Isn't while a looping mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_loop)?

Comment: @Divakar Yes it is. Vectorization and looping are not mutually exclusive. Sometimes it is beneficial to vectorize only some part of the algorithm. While the first approach requires looping proportional to the input size, the second approach only loops if there are `np.nan` values below each other, so it is not dependent on the input size.

Comment: My contention is just regarding terminology. If you think most of the computation is outside of that while-loop or with the first iteration, you could call it partly or partial vectorization. At least that's how I go with terminology.

Comment: @Divakar I would consider a portion of code vectorized if it does not include looping over array dimensions. And would use partially vectorized if it loops only along some dims but not others. I would not know which of the two nomenclature for *partial* vectorization is most used.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a vectorized NumPy based one inspired by [`Most efficient way to forward-fill NaN values in numpy array's answer post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41191127/) -

```
def ffill_cols(a, startfillval=0):
    mask = np.isnan(a)
    tmp = a[0].copy()
    a[0][mask[0]] = startfillval
    mask[0] = False
    idx = np.where(~mask,np.arange(mask.shape[0])[:,None],0)
    out = np.take_along_axis(a,np.maximum.accumulate(idx,axis=0),axis=0)
    a[0] = tmp
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [2]: a
Out[2]: 
array([[ 5., nan, nan,  7.,  2.,  6.,  5.],
       [ 3., nan,  1.,  8., nan,  5., nan],
       [ 4.,  9.,  6., nan, nan, nan,  7.]])

In [3]: ffill_cols(a)
Out[3]: 
array([[5., 0., 0., 7., 2., 6., 5.],
       [3., 0., 1., 8., 2., 5., 5.],
       [4., 9., 6., 8., 2., 5., 7.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[  5.,  np.nan,  np.nan,   7.,   2.,   6.,   5.],
                [  3.,  np.nan,   1.,   8.,  np.nan,   5.,  np.nan],
                [  4.,   9.,   6.,  np.nan,  np.nan,  np.nan,   7.]])

nan_indices = np.isnan(arr)
```

Where nan_indices gives you:

```
array([[False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False]])
```

Now it's just a matter of replacing the values using the logic you mentioned in the question:

```
arr[0, nan_indices[0, :]] = 0

for row in range(1, np.shape(arr)[0]):
    arr[row, nan_indices[row, :]] = arr[row - 1, nan_indices[row, :]]
```

Now arr is:

```
array([[5., 0., 0., 7., 2., 6., 5.],
       [3., 0., 1., 8., 2., 5., 5.],
       [4., 9., 6., 8., 2., 5., 7.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[  5.,  np.nan,  np.nan,   7.,   2.,   6.,   5.],
             [  3.,  np.nan,   1.,   8.,  np.nan,   5.,  np.nan],
             [  4.,   9.,   6.,  np.nan,  np.nan,  np.nan,   7.]])

def fillnans(a):
    a[0, np.isnan(a[0,:])] = 0
    while np.any(np.isnan(a)):
        a[np.isnan(a)] = np.roll(a, 1, 0)[np.isnan(a)]
    return a

print(x)
print(fillnans(x))
```

#### Output

```
[[ 5. nan nan  7.  2.  6.  5.]
 [ 3. nan  1.  8. nan  5. nan]
 [ 4.  9.  6. nan nan nan  7.]]
[[5. 0. 0. 7. 2. 6. 5.]
 [3. 0. 1. 8. 2. 5. 5.]
 [4. 9. 6. 8. 2. 5. 7.]]
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
from numpy import *

a = array([[5.,  nan,  nan,   7.,   2.,   6.,   5.],
[3.,  nan,   1.,   8.,  nan,   5.,  nan],
[4.,   9.,   6.,  nan,  nan,  nan,   7.]])
```

replace nan with zeros in first row

```
where_are_NaNs = isnan(a[0])
a[0][where_are_NaNs] = 0
```

replace nan in other rows

```
where_are_NaNs = isnan(a)
for i in range(len(where_are_NaNs)):
    for j in range(len(where_are_NaNs[0])):
        if(where_are_NaNs[i][j]):
            a[i][j] = a[i-1][j]
```