# dataframe column created from another column variations via vectorization

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, vectorization

I have a dataframe like this with two columns, `date` and `indicator` :

```
date                  indicator 
2019-10-26 06:48:49   -1.073525
2019-10-27 06:19:31   -0.375276
2019-10-28 06:50:44    0.643764
2019-10-29 07:21:35    0.863731
2019-10-30 07:52:36    1.022312
2019-10-31 08:23:18    1.125842
2019-11-01 08:52:35    0.863731
2019-11-02 09:16:28    0.831097
2019-11-03 09:42:20    0.529638
2019-11-04 10:09:01   -0.735926
2019-11-05 10:34:39   -1.743626
2019-11-06 11:00:39   -0.872055
```

the idea would be to create a column `signal`, without doing a loop, which works like this :

- if `indicator` < -1 then :

  - if `signal` was 0, it becomes 1 and keeps this value until `indicator`
    become positive
  - if `signal` was already 1 it doesn't change
- if `indicator` > 1 then :

  - if `signal` was 0, it becomes -1 and keeps this value until `indicator`
    become negative
  - if `signal` was already -1 it doesn't change
- if `indicator` changes sign :

  - if `signal` was -1 or 1 it becomes 0
  - if `signal` was 0 it doesn't change

so it would give something like :

```
date                  indicator    signal 
2019-10-26 06:48:49   -1.073525      1
2019-10-27 06:19:31   -0.375276      1
2019-10-28 06:50:44    0.643764      0
2019-10-29 07:21:35    0.863731      0 
2019-10-30 07:52:36    1.022312     -1
2019-10-31 08:23:18    1.125842     -1
2019-11-01 08:52:35    0.863731     -1 
2019-11-02 09:16:28    0.831097     -1 
2019-11-03 09:42:20    0.529638     -1
2019-11-04 10:09:01   -0.735926      0  
2019-11-05 10:34:39   -1.743626      1
2019-11-06 11:00:39   -0.872055      1
```

i tried to create some column with 1 and -1 depending on indicator value then do a diff and cumulative sum but didn't succeed to obtain this exact column.

Comment: `if indicator changes sign, then from 1 or -1 to 0` I didn't quite get this part. Please elaborate on this.

Comment: Even based on these conditions `if indicator < -1 then 1` and `if indicator > 1 then -1` , the column doesn't follow these properties always. Or maybe I am not getting them.

Comment: As @Rishabh Kumar exactly mentioned, there are inconsistencies in what you indicated you want to do. Redefine values for "signal" (especially for the cases of "0") or what you want to achieve. E.g. in the second row, based on what you wrote "signal" should have a value of 0.

Comment: Sorry, i've just edited with clarification, should be good now, thanks !

Comment: Can you share what you have already tried?

Comment: your description is incomplete:
1) what if indicator<-1 and signal was -1?
2) what if indicator > 1 and signal was +1?
3) what to do for the very first row?

in any case, I am afraid what you describe here cannot be done without a loop (only for the rows where indicator changes signs you can since there signal is always 0 no-matter what was the previous signal value)

Comment: @Amir the first two situations can't exist as it come back to 0 if `indicator` changes sign, for your third point I consider that the value of `signal` was 0 before the first row

Comment: @d3dave i tried to do a column of `signal.diff()` then a column with `signal.diff().cumsum()` as i did for another one but this time it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure `numpy` solution without using `np.vectorize`:

```
indicator_np = df.indicator.to_numpy()
indicator_abs_gt1 = np.abs(indicator_np)>1
np.sign(indicator_np, out=indicator_np)
signchanges = np.ediff1d(indicator_np, to_begin=0).astype(bool)
signal = np.where(
    indicator_abs_gt1 | signchanges, 
    -indicator_np* indicator_abs_gt1, 
    np.nan
)
mask = np.isnan(signal)                   ##
idx = np.arange(mask.size) * ~mask        ##  Inspired from Divakar's answer -
np.maximum.accumulate(idx, out=idx)       ##  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41191127/5431791
df['signal'] = signal[idx].astype(int)    ##

>>> df
date                  indicator    signal 
2019-10-26 06:48:49   -1.073525      1
2019-10-27 06:19:31   -0.375276      1
2019-10-28 06:50:44    0.643764      0
2019-10-29 07:21:35    0.863731      0 
2019-10-30 07:52:36    1.022312     -1
2019-10-31 08:23:18    1.125842     -1
2019-11-01 08:52:35    0.863731     -1 
2019-11-02 09:16:28    0.831097     -1 
2019-11-03 09:42:20    0.529638     -1
2019-11-04 10:09:01   -0.735926      0  
2019-11-05 10:34:39   -1.743626      1
2019-11-06 11:00:39   -0.872055      1
```

Although the performance improvement from the currently accepted solution **for the sample data provided in the question** is negligible, the improvement is **huge** when the size of data increases significantly.

**SETUP**

```
def pure_np(series):
    indicator_np = series.to_numpy()
    indicator_abs_gt1 = np.abs(indicator_np)>1
    np.sign(indicator_np, out=indicator_np)
    signchanges = np.ediff1d(indicator_np, to_begin=0).astype(bool)
    signal = np.where(indicator_abs_gt1 | signchanges, -indicator_np* indicator_abs_gt1, np.nan)
    mask = np.isnan(signal)
    idx = np.arange(mask.size) * ~mask
    np.maximum.accumulate(idx, out=idx)
    return signal[idx].astype(int)

def conditions(x):
    global s
    if x > 1:
        s = -1
    elif x < -1:
        s = 1
    else:
        if ((s == -1) & (x < 0)) | ((s == 1) & (x > 0)) :
            s = 0
    return s
df['signal'] = [0] * len(df)
TmSmth = np.vectorize(conditions)
```

**Benchmark**:

```
>>> df.shape    # sample df
(12, 2)

>>> %timeit TmSmth(df["indicator"])
45.7 µs ± 814 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
>>> %timeit pure_np(df["indicator"])
39.2 µs ± 450 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)  ~ 1.1X speed-up

>>> df = pd.concat([df]*1_000, ignore_index=True)
>>> df.shape
(12000, 2)

>>> %timeit TmSmth(df["indicator"])
5.5 ms ± 73.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
>>> %timeit pure_np(df["indicator"])
265 µs ± 5.25 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)   ~ 21X speed-up


>>> df = pd.concat([df]*1_000, ignore_index=True)   # 12 million rows
>>> df.shape
(12000000, 2)

>>> %timeit TmSmth(df['indicator'])
6.43 s ± 455 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
>>> %timeit pure_np(df['indicator'])
448 ms ± 58.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)       ~14X speed-up
```

Comment: that's amazing, thank you ! but how on earth you can find a logic like this, what's the reasoning behind the maximum.accumulate thing ?

Comment: It is like `itertools.accumulate` with `max` function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you insist on not doing a loop, but I have a **partial solution**:

```
df['signal'] = [None] * len(df)
df['signal'][df['indicator'] < -1] = 1
df['signal'][df['indicator'] > 1] = -1

loc = df.rolling(window=2).indicator.aggregate(lambda x: x.iloc[0] * x.iloc[1] < 0).fillna(0)
df['signal'][loc > 0] = 0
```

This results in:

```
    indicator signal
0   -1.073525      1
1   -0.375276   None
2    0.643764      0
3    0.863731   None
4    1.022312     -1
5    1.125842     -1
6    0.863731   None
7    0.831097   None
8    0.529638   None
9   -0.735926      0
10  -1.743626      1
11  -0.872055   None
```

From here you need to fill the `None`s to the value before, which I am not sure how to do without looping.

Comment: Could you explain the idea of the loc please ? And i prefer not doing a loop for performance reason, i've always heard that for big dataframe you can really lose a lot of time doing a loop and you have to prefer vectorisation

Comment: Edit : i got the loc idea, i'm waiting for a complete solution if possible for now thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've found something which works, even if it can be optimized i guess. It's based on @user4340135 answer here [Numpy "where" with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109045/numpy-where-with-multiple-conditions). I add a global variable to retain the last value :

```
def conditions(x):
    global s
    if x > 1:
        s = -1
    elif x < -1:
        s = 1
    else:
        if ((s == -1) & (x < 0)) | ((s == 1) & (x > 0)) :
            s = 0
    return s
        
        
df['signal'] = [0] * len(a)
func = np.vectorize(conditions)
df['signal'] = func(df["indicator"])
```

Comment: I guess this almost works, but you first need to check if value changed signs and only then check if abs>1, since if it was negative and changed to +2 signal should return 0.

Comment: I don't understand ? The `if` after the `else` checks for the change of sign.For example if `s = -1` and `x` is négative, it means that it changed sign as `s = - 1` only if `x > 0` and come was above 1 at some time.

Comment: if indicator is:
`[-2, 3, 3]`
according to your explanation the signal should become
`[1, 0, -1]`
since it changed signs from -2 to 3, while in this solution it becomes
`[1, -1, -1]`

Comment: No it's ok because if it's 3 it changed signs but it's also above 1 so it becomes -1 for the signal, the sign check was for indicator between -1 and 1 not included, sorry if it was not clear

Comment: Please see the comment you gave me on the original question (not answer), I asked you specifically for this case and you answered: "@Amir the first two situations can't exist as it come back to 0 if indicator changes sign"

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.where()` can be used with two or even more conditional parts as follow:

`numpy.where((condion1)|(condition2))` for `or` problems

`numpy.where((condion1)&(condition2))` for `and` problems

and the output of `numpy.where()` can be use in this way `df.iloc[out_put_of_numpy_where]`. Although I didn't quit understand the problem this will solve it.