# Propagate/forward-fill nan values in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I need to forward-fill nan values in a `numpy` array along the columns (`axis=0`). I am looking for a pure `numpy` solution that yields the same result as `pd.fillna(method="ffill")`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arr = np.array(
    [
        [5, np.nan, 3],
        [4, np.nan, np.nan],
        [6, 2, np.nan],
        [2, np.nan, 6],
    ]
)

expected = pd.DataFrame(arr).fillna(method="ffill", axis=0)  # I need this line in pure numpy

print(f"Original array:\n {arr}\n")
print(f"Expected array:\n {expected.values}\n")

Original array:
 [[ 5. nan  3.]
 [ 4. nan nan]
 [ 6.  2. nan]
 [ 2. nan  6.]]

Expected array:
 [[ 5. nan  3.]
 [ 4. nan  3.]
 [ 6.  2.  3.]
 [ 2.  2.  6.]]
```

Comment: I had this same issue. Frustrated the hell out of me. Ended up using a chained pandas instruction. [pd.Series(array).bfill().to_numpy()].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No inbuilt function in numpy to do this. Below simple code will generate desired result using numpy array only.

```
row,col = arr.shape
mask = np.isnan(arr)
for i in range(1,row):
    for j in range(col):
        if mask[i][j]:
            arr[i][j] =arr[i-1][j]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Bottleneck push function](https://kwgoodman.github.io/bottleneck-doc/reference.html#bottleneck.push) is a good option to forward fill. It's normally used internally in packages like Xarray.

```
from bottleneck import push
push(arr, axis=0)
```

Comment: Usually this answer would be sufficient, however, I am not able to install the package in my environment. Hence, I am looking for a pure ``numpy`` (or maybe ``numba``) solution.

Comment: This link might help with various : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41190852/most-efficient-way-to-forward-fill-nan-values-in-numpy-array