# python replace value in array based on previous and following value in column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, replace

given the following array, I want to replace the zero with their previous value columnwise as long as it is surrounded by two values greater than zero.
I am aware of np.where but it would consider the whole array instead of its columns.
I am not sure how to do it and help would be appreciated.

This is the array:

```
a=np.array([[4, 3, 3, 2],
            [0, 0, 1, 2],
            [0, 4, 2, 4],
            [2, 4, 3, 0]])
```

and since the only zero that meets this condition is the second row/second column one,
the new array should be the following

```
new_a=np.array([[4, 3, 3, 2],
               [0, 3, 1, 2],
               [0, 4, 2, 4],
               [2, 4, 3, 0]])
```

How do I accomplish this?

And what if I would like to extend the gap surrounded by nonzero ? For instance, the first column contains two 0 and the second column contains one 0, so the new array would be

```
new_a=np.array([[4, 3, 3, 2],
               [4, 3, 1, 2],
               [4, 4, 2, 4],
               [2, 4, 3, 0]])
```

In short, how do I solve this if the columnwise condition would be the one of having N  consecutive zeros or less?

Comment: Surrounded how? top/down? top/down/left/right? Any 7 neighbor?

Comment: top down, since I am considering columns

Answer (score 1):

As a generic method, I would approach this using a convolution:

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

# kernel for top/down neighbors
kernel = np.array([[1],
                   [0],
                   [1]])
# is the value a zero?
m1 = a==0
# count non-zeros neighbors
m2 = convolve2d(~m1, kernel, mode='same') > 1

mask = m1&m2

# replace matching values with previous row value
a[mask] = np.roll(a, 1, axis=0)[mask]
```

output:

```
array([[4, 3, 3, 2],
       [0, 3, 1, 2],
       [0, 4, 2, 4],
       [2, 4, 3, 0]])
```

##### filling from surrounding values

Using [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) to benefit from [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html)/[`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) (you can forward-fill in pure numpy [but its more complex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41190852/most-efficient-way-to-forward-fill-nan-values-in-numpy-array)):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(a)

# limit for neighbors
N = 2

# identify non-zeros
m = df.ne(0)
# mask zeros
m2 = m.where(m)
# mask for values with 2 neighbors within limits
mask = m2.ffill(limit=N) & m2.bfill(limit=N)
df.mask(mask&~m).ffill()

array([[4, 3, 3, 2],
       [4, 3, 1, 2],
       [4, 4, 2, 4],
       [2, 4, 3, 0]])
```

Comment: your solution works for this example, but if I would like to increase the threshold to >2 or 3,4.... changing the parameter in m2 does not work. What needs to be done in this case?

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: let's for instance say that the value in between has to be 0 but the adjacent values columnwise must be greater than 2 or greater than 3 etc.... how would this code change?

Comment: I see, then `m2 = convolve2d(a>3, kernel, mode='same') > 1` for greater than 3

Comment: Thanks. And what if you want to widen the gap? e.g. 2 or less zeros? This way, the first column would be 4,4,4,2 and the second 3,3,4,4 while the 3rd and 4th columns would remain the same ?

Comment: Again, a specific example would be more explicit. But you can use any kernel size for the convolution

Comment: that's the example, but in the first column there are 2 zeros, so what if I want to extend the condition to include two or N consecutive zeros instead of just one ? I have tried to enlarge the kernel but it did not work

Comment: Please edit the question with a clear example

Comment: ok, I have just edited it

Comment: @user18735627 while you can do this in pure numpy it's a bit tedious, I would use pandas for that (see update)

Answer (score 0):

That's one solution I found. I know it's basic but I think it works.

```
a=np.array([[4, 3, 3, 2],
            [0, 0, 1, 2],
            [0, 4, 2, 4],
            [2, 4, 3, 0]])
a_t = a.T

for i in range(len(a_t)):
    ar = a_t[i]
    for j in range(len(ar)-1):
        if (j>0) and (ar[j] == 0) and (ar[j+1] > 0):
            a_t[i][j] = a_t[i][j-1]
a = a_t.T
```