# Processing all cells in a 2d DataFrame is very slow - what am I missing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, performance

I have a dataframe that comes from a csv file. I pivot this dataframe by two columns, and then attempt to process each cell.

In my actual code, which is of course much more complicated, there is some processing for each value. But I notice it is extremely slow. I then created a canonical example here to illustrate the issue where I don't do anything to the value - I just iterate through them and assign the same value back to each cell - which eliminates my processing as the issue and highlights the access / assignment as being slow:

```
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm


def test_speed():
    df = pd.read_csv('https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/datablist/sample-csv-files/main/files/customers/customers-100.csv')
    df = pd.pivot(df, index='Index', columns='Country')

    original = df.copy()

    inputs = df.columns.values

    # process each row at a time
    for row_index in tqdm(range(df.shape[0])): 
        row_data = df.iloc[row_index]  # get the row

        for input_idx in range(len(inputs)):
            # for each column label, get the value
            val = row_data[inputs[input_idx]]  

            # just assign them back to that cell 
            df.iloc[row_index, input_idx] = val  location

    print(f'Are they equal? {original.equals(df)}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_speed()
```

I am getting this:

```
100%|██████████| 100/100 [00:04<00:00, 22.63it/s]
Are they equal? True
```

So, just 22 rows processed per second.

If I do the same processing iterating through the csv using a `DictReader` I get about 5000 rows per iteration.

I am obviously missing something important on how to access cells in a `DataFrame`.

My objective is to traverse all cells in this 2d pivot table and assign the value (possibly altered) back in an efficient way.

How can I speed up this code?

**UPDATE:** if I do the processing before pivot, it goes up to 1600 iterations / second. I think whenever I assign anything indexes are being rebuilt? I am never assigning values to the row / column I used to pivot, so this is surprising - any way to keep the pivot and the performance?

Comment: the loop shown is an *"anti-pattern in action"*

Comment: Extract all values from the dataframe (`df.values`) and work on the numpy array instead of dataframe. Less readable, much much faster

Comment: Though it's possible to iterate over the rows of dataframe with a for-loop, this is not what pandas dataframes are optimized for. Normally your goal should be to use **vectorized** operations instead, as these offer much greater speed.

Comment: Maybe if you [edit] your question and put what exact computation do you need (+sample date/expected output) we can help you to make it faster.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest making this kind of comment and leaving at that is a n anti-pattern in this community. Obviously something is wrong with this code, otherwise I would not be here asking about, no? It is more productive to share some of your wisdom, but silence is ok too. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @dankal444, I'll operate on numpy instead - thatsa great suggestion! If you want to move this to an answer I can accept it - thanks again!

Comment: I second AndrejKesely's suggestion. If you show us a [mre] with your data operations, then we can give more targeted advice (such as for example vectorized code alternatives to your for-loops).

Comment: Thanks everyone! I thought the code I included was a valid minimal reproducible example. Its a co.plete, self contained program that shows the issue at hand. The processing is not relevant to the problem (as I can reproduce it without it - the issuewas in the loop and/assigment), so i took it out. - what am I missing?

Comment: Hi! I think it would be easier if you provided some sample input for people to play with. Numpy is probably the way to go if you just have numbers as input. Otherwise, as I think iterrows could be useful (`for index, row in df.iterrows():`), or something as simple as `df["new_column'] = df['Country']*2`, depending on how you're processing your data?

Comment: @EdyBourne Yes, you have indeed posted a very good minimal reproducible example. However you say that you have left out the various data processing operations that happen inside the for-loops in your 'real' code. My point is this: depending on what data operations exactly you're doing, it may be possible to rewrite your code such that use of for-loops is completely eliminated (and replaced with faster alternatives).

Comment: @EdyBourne [Here's an example of a question in which I presented code with for-loops on a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41190852/most-efficient-way-to-forward-fill-nan-values-in-numpy-array), to which Divakar replied with a solution that was an order of magnitude faster thanks to complete elimination of the for loops (replacing them with vectorized operations).

Comment: To summarize what others have said: without seeing a nontrivial example of your actual data processing operation, it's not possible to comment on what kinds of improvements are possible. Normally in Pandas you can operate on whole columns at once, sometimes even whole dataframes at once. This should result in significantly improved performance. But without an understanding of what you're doing, it's impossible for anyone to suggest a technique along those lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### working on numpy array

Extract all values from the dataframe (`df.values`) and work on the numpy array instead of dataframe.

Less readable, much much faster.

#### vectorization

As other said in comments, using **vectorized** operations will make whole thing even faster, by removing need for python for loops. However, I am not sure if you need to improve performance further though (and “premature optimization is the root of all evil”)

#### numba

Sometimes vectorization is hard or even impossible to code using available pandas/numpy functions. In such cases it may be possible to use `numba` package. If the code you have is *numba-compatible*, you should get huge performance improvement.