# How to apply lower and upper threshold to NumPy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following array

```
array = np.array([-0.5, -2, -1, -0.5, -0.25, 0, 0, -2, -1, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2])
```

and would like to apply two thresholds, such that all values below `-1.0` are set to `1` and all values *above* `-0.3` are set to `0`. For the values inbetween, the following rule should apply: if the last value was below `-1.0` then it should be a `1` but if the last value was above `-0.3`, then it should be a `0`.

For the example array above, the output should be

```
target = np.array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

If multiple consecutive values are between `-1.0` and `-0.3`, then it should go back as far as required until there is a value above or below the two thresholds and set the output accordingly.

I tried to achieve this by iterating over the array and using a `while` inside the for loop to find the next occurence where the value is above the threshold, but it doesn't work:

```
array = np.array([-0.5, -2, -1, -0.5, -0.25, 0, 0, -2, -1, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2])

p = []

def function(array, p):
    for i in np.nditer(array):
       if i < -1: 
          while i <= -0.3:
            p.append(1)
            i += 1
          else:
            p.append(0)
            i += 1
    return p

a = function(array, p)
print(a)
```

How can I apply the two thresholds to my array as described above?

Comment: Why would we return 0 first in the list of -0.5 is the first item in the array? Maybe I am missing something here.

Comment: What is the expected result for `function([-5])`?

Comment: We should return 0 for the first item because the threshold for the first item is <= -1. Edited to reflect this.

Comment: The expected result is: np.array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]) as demonstrated in the code

Comment: Is it possible that there is an error in the desired result, and that it should actually be `[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]`, i.e. three and not only two zeros in the middle?

Comment: No, if the threshold for first indicating is <= 1 and the threshold for ending indication is <= -0.3.

Comment: But `-0.25, 0, 0` are three values which are larger than `-0.3`, so it should be three zeros, shouldn't it?

Comment: You are correct, I am sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is called "thresholding with hysteresis". For this, I adapted the very nice algorithm from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23291658/4221706):

Given your test data,

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array([-0.5, -2, -1, -0.5, -0.25, 0, 0, -2, -1, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2])
```

you detect which values are below the first threshold `-1.0`, and which are above the second threshold `-0.3`:

```
low_values = array <= -1.0
high_values = array >= -0.3
```

These are the values for which you know the result: either `1` or `0`. For all other values, it depends on its neighbors. Thus, all values for which either `low_values` or `high_values` is `True` are known.
You can get the indices of all known elements with:

```
known_values = high_values | low_values
known_idx = np.nonzero(known_values)[0]
```

To find the result for all unknown values, we use the [`np.cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) function on the `known_values` array. The Booleans are interpreted as `0` or `1`, so this gives us the following array:

```
acc = np.cumsum(known_values)
```

which will result in the following for your example:
`[ 0  1  2  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]`.
Now, `known_idx[acc - 1]` will contain the index of the last known value for each point. With `low_values[known_idx[acc - 1]]` you get a `True` if the last known value was below `-1.0` and a `False` if it was above `-0.3`:

```
result = low_values[known_idx[acc - 1]]
```

There is one problem left: If the initial value is below `-1.0` or above `-0.3`, then everything works out perfectly fine. But if it is in-between, then it would depend on its left neighbor - which it doesn't have. So in your case, you simply define it to be zero.

We can do that by checking if `acc[0]` equals `0` or `1`. If `acc[0] = 1`, then everything is fine, but if `acc[0] = 0`, then this means that the first value is between `-1.0` and `-0.3`, so we have to set it to zero:

```
if not acc[0]:
    result[0] = False
```

Finally, as we were doing lots of comparisons, our `result` array is a boolean array. To convert it to integer `0` and `1`, we simply call

```
result = np.int8(result)
```

and we get our desired result:

```
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int8)
```

Comment: This solution is correct. I suppose I was thinking of the problem incorrectly, but did not know about thresholding with hysteresis. Thank you!